# SQLAlchemy reports "Invalid utf8mb4 character string" for BINARY column

Tags: sqlalchemy, mysql-python

Assuming this MySQL table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

When I use the `execute()` API from SQLAlchemy connection class as such:

```
with self.engine.begin() as connection:
  user_uuid = uuid.UUID("...")
  result = connection.execute("SELECT email, name, photo FROM user WHERE uuid=%s", user_uuid.bytes)
```

If the UUID is `F393A167-A919-4B50-BBB7-4AD356E89E6B`, then SQLAlchemy prints this warning:

> /site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:450: Warning: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'F393A1'

The `uuid` column is a `BINARY` column, so why is SQLAlchemy considering this parameter a text one instead of a binary one and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation and solution is actually in this [bug report in MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79317):

> replace:
>
> cursor.execute("""
>       INSERT INTO `user` (uuid)
>       VALUES (%s)
>   """, my_uuid)
>
> with
>
> cursor.execute("""
>       INSERT INTO `user` (uuid)
>       VALUES (_binary %s)
>   """, my_uuid)
>
> Mind the underscore. It's "_binary", not "binary".
>   This "_binary" tells MySQL that the following string is to be interpreted as binary, not to be interpreted/validated as utf8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't happen on Python 3, so I think that the problem is that the database driver is unable to distinguish what should be bytes given the Python 2 `str` type.

Regardless, it seems using SQLAlchemy core directly works correctly, presumably because it knows the column type directly.

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, select

meta = MetaData()
user = Table('user', meta, autoload_with=engine)
result = select([user]).where(user.c.uuid == user_uuid.bytes)
```

If you wish to continue executing a string, you can cast to bytesarray like SQLAlchemy appears to be doing:

```
with self.engine.begin() as connection:
    user_uuid = uuid.UUID("...")
    result = connection.execute(
        "SELECT email, name, photo FROM user WHERE uuid=%s",
        bytearray(user_uuid.bytes))
```

Or to tell SQLAlchemy what type the bound parameter is to get this automatically:

```
from sqlalchemy import text, bindparam, BINARY

with self.engine.begin() as connection:
    user_uuid = uuid.UUID("...")
    stmt = text("SELECT email, name, photo FROM user WHERE uuid = :uuid")
    stmt = stmt.bindparams(bindparam('uuid', user_uuid.bytes, type_=BINARY))
    result = connection.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: You're most likely right about the Python 2 `str` vs `unicode` problem. If you log the SQL commands issued by SQLAlchemy Core, what does it use?

Comment: It uses `bytearray` on Python 2, and `bytes` on Python 3.

Comment: I mean what's the actual SQL generated by SQLAlchemy Core and passed to the MySQL driver (it's visible by setting `echo=True` on the engine)?

Comment: @Pol I know, that's what I used. It's `SELECT tbl.uuid FROM tbl WHERE tbl.uuid = %(uuid_1)s` and the only difference is the next log line with the passed value (`bytes` vs `bytearray`)

Comment: So it's not putting `_binary` in the SQL. I'm not sure why it works then. Maybe the MySQL driver sees the `bytearray` type and adds it automatically...

Comment: @Pol I think this has answered your question, can you mark it correct if it has?